# Input data in database (e.g. via browser)

Tags: web-apps, database, web-browser, user-interface

my company is very restrictive regarding new software and even programming languages. Basically I am limited to everything which is preinstalled on my PC, which is the Microsoft Office/365 Suite (thus I "could" use VBA), Browser, Access and maybe PowerShell.

I need a software which allows a normal user putting data into a SQL database (MSSQL). Microsoft Access is used quite frequently for this task, which I dislike. Same for VBA.

So I thought maybe building something within the browser for a easy accessible, easy to use and modern interface for inserting data into a database.

Is there a framework, based on technology which can be run in the browser (e.g. Javascript..), which allows me building input forms? Please note, I must be client-side only, since I can't use a server application for it.

Other solutions, e.g. based on PowerShell, Microsoft Cloud or whatever is also welcomed. Please just note, I can't use anything like Python and so on.

Comment: You want something like this, right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60454182/how-can-i-make-a-valid-sql-command-out-of-this-gui

Comment: Does you and your colleagues have to upload CVS or edit rows manually?

Comment: The company in which you are working is still living in the '90. Telle them to grow up. You cannot keep using Microsoft Access to do these tasks. The world has changed. They have to use modern software and code

Comment: @FrancescoMantovani, imagine the worst. That's how it is. It's really awful... "We don't trust Python"... Basically, I am one of very few how actively use databases. Some people use Oracle SQL Developer or something similar. By the way, we are in the high-tech field... Your link with PowerShell is helpful, thanks, I will try.

Comment: you look like a guy that want to find a solution to problems. Maybe you are not working in the right company. You should change job